# Show progress of image download using Novoda's ImageLoader

Tags: android, imageview, image-loading

I'm using Novoda's Image downloader and I'm wondering if it is possible to see the progress of an image being downloaded.

I've googled a bit but there was no conclusive answer.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The Novoda imageloader has been deprecated and further development is not being undertaken. At this time, there are no callbacks available on the library to get an indication of progress.